# Looping send_keys() function causing 'NoneType' object error

Tags: python, selenium

I have a tuple (names) that has 2 lists in it. list1 contains last names, list2 contains first names. Im trying to loop through each list and send the first and last name to 2 textarea fields on a website. The first time the loop runs everyhthing works perfectly, but the second time I get an error `Exception has occurred: TypeError 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` Im assuming the `send_keys()` is returning a value of none and is somehow screwing things up.

Here is the my code for generating the lists and tuple. The info is being read from an excel sheet.

```
def get_names(book):
f_names = []
l_names = []
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(book)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for y in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    l_names.append(worksheet.cell_value(y, 0))  
    f_names.append(worksheet.cell_value(y, 1))

return (l_names, f_names)`
```

In my main program I have the following loop running:

```
   import xlrd
   from selenium import webdriver

   url = 'https://website.com'
   driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
   driver.get(url)

   for i in range(len(names[0])):
      lName = driver.find_element_by_id('id_last_name')
      lName.send_keys(names[0][i])
      fName = driver.find_element_by_id('id_first_name')
      fName.send_keys(names[1][I])

      search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table-responsive"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input').click()
```

Once `send_keys()` enters the name in the field. the program is suppose to start over and enter the next name in the list.
Can someone tell me how to fix this, or a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example as well your tuple?

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the return value of `.send_keys()`, so that cannot possibly be the problem.  Either `names` itself is None, `names[0]` is None, or `names[1]` is None - without the full traceback message, I can't tell which of those is the case.

Comment: Hey guys! I updated the code, hopefully this helps. please forgive if this seems trivial. im very new with selenium. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try initialize:

```
   for i in range(len(names[0])):
    lName, fname = "",""

    lName = driver.find_element_by_id('id_last_name')
    lName.send_keys(names[0][i])
    fName = driver.find_element_by_id('id_first_name')
    fName.send_keys(names[1][i])
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried that and still have the same issue. I've also tried `lName.clear()` on a new line after the `send_keys()` call and that didn't work either.